# Would security.stackexchange.com be a good place to ask this question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I had earlier posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1268581/security-review-of-popular-browser-extensions-addons?noredirect=1#comment1869649_1268581) question to superuser. Got a comment suggesting that I ask the question here.

What I want to know is, where can I find trusted and open (in the foss sense) security reviews of chrome/firefox extensions.

Answer (score 5):

No. "Where to find a resource" questions are generally off-topic across most of the SE sites, because the answers are simply links to an external site.

To answer your question, you won't find what you are looking for. Any security review becomes obsolete once the code is updated. Closed source code reviews will be posted by the vendor (and then only as a snapshot in time). And there is little commercial benefit for someone to take on the potential liability for reviewing FOSS code and declaring it in a certain state or not.

Security reviews are useful for the vendor, but they introduce liabilities for all involved. So, they tend to be kept private.

Comment: Why do you say closed source? I'm under the impression that all browser add-ons are essentially open source (at least the client side of things). The question that I'm trying to answer here, is whether the evernote web clipper sends up my browsing history and contents of tabs that I haven't clipped to evernote's servers. Seems the only way to do it is dive into the code myself, but that is something that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Closed source does not mean "not discoverable"